# Gamma correction in python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

Gamma correction is a simple and elegant algorithm to change the image brightness.
The formula is:
[image]
But unfortunately this algorithm is not implemented in opencv.
So how is the simplest way to do it in python?

Answer (score 2):

Gamma correction with open CV using a LUT:

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
    # their adjusted gamma values
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
    # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
    return cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

[Source](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/)